# Creating secondary menu bar under the first one ORACLE APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to create a secondary menu under the first one?

[image]

So another menu bar under 'Home, Team/People' and above 'Home' Title

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you don't create them as a Menu. In APEX (At least with theme 42) you have to choose Side Navigation or Top Navigation (not both).

What I've done is define my side menu then I added items to the Navigation list (in my case I have no need for submenus on the Nav. Bar)  and the end result is that I have items to click on on left and top.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. So, you can have only one menu list, which is for the application in general, but what you could do is add a region on page 0 which represents a list.

---

I'm assuming you're familiar with APEX development, then you can follow these steps:

1. Fist you need to have the page 0(a.k.a global page) in your application. So, create it if there's not.
2. In page 0, create a new region.
3. Set the following region's attributes:

   **Type:** List;

   **Position:** Page Navigation;

   **Template:** none (- Select -).

   In source tab, **select** which list do you want to display there.